# node js - storing large numbers in ArrayBuffer

Tags: node.js, arraybuffer

Consider this code:

```
var b = new ArrayBuffer(2);

b[0] = 1;
b[1] = 23234322442;
```

The number in cell number 1 is clearly larger than 1 byte, yet the ArrayBuffer has no problem storing it, and when I print `b` to console I can see the number is there. What's the explanation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ArrayBuffer object is used to represent a generic, fixed-length raw binary data buffer. You cannot directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer; instead, you create one of the typed array objects or a DataView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer. [*more*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)

So, I think, when you call `b[1]` then you don't set second element of buffer. You simple set `b.1` property of object and it can be anything (number, string, object, array).